# Cервер анонимного чата на Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, чат, chat

Получил техническое задание на создание анонимного чата. **Сервер чата должен быть построен с использованием Web API**.

Ранее не приходилось в продакшене строить какой-либо чат. Но всегда знал, что есть такая замечательная штука как `SignalR`, которая при необходимости поможет мне в пару шагов создать чат. Но с этим ТЗ не тут-то было.

Все поисковые запросы так или иначе наводят на `SignalR` или `сокеты`. Не могу найти подходящий туториал ни для `Web API` ни для `WCF`.

Также сказано, что чат должен выдерживать нагрузку при одновременной переписки **10.000 пользователей**. Быть может из-за этого требуется что-то не стандартное?

В какую сторону мне копать? Или быть может следует как-то уточнить ТЗ у заказчика?

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема? 10к пользователей - это очень немного, с этим справится любой асинхронный сервер. Web API и WCF - оба асинхронные.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, в проекте `Web API` используется `SignalR`? Или? Экшен для получения сообщения и сохранения его в БД я смогу сделать. А как происходит перенаправление этого сообщения остальным пользователям?

Comment: Так это уже вам самому надо написать.